# How to change base url to subdirectory CakePHP?

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, cakephp, url-rewriting

I have a cakephp 3 script installed on my cpanel account.

this domain is the primary domain for account but i have relocated it to a subfolder for necessary reasons.

my htaccess rewrites it perfectly and every url works both with and without /subfolder/ in the url.

However, all the links in cakephp automatically append /subfolder/ back into the url.

I even tried manually replacing $base_url in configuration.php with 'mydomain.com'; only, but that didn't work. Then I replaced every instance in all the hundreds of files of $base_url with 'mydomain.com'; but still, nothing changed and it still shows that /subfolder/ in every url even when i access mydomain.com directly._

I need to get rid of this /subfolder/ in the url that cakephp is serving from php. i tried everything i knew but nothing works.

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `App.base`, `App.webroot`? Setting those values up will disable automatic directory detection and should help you get the URLs you want. See [configuration docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#general-configuration) for more on those values.